# HTTP closing connection with just one FIN package

Tags: tcp

While on wireshark, I tried to connect to some site using http protocol. When I followed the TCP stream I saw that there was just one FIN package. How could this happen?

**Edit:**

The problem is I didn't save the capture and now each time I try to replicate it I obtain two handshakes I can tell [http://elpais.com/](http://this) is the webpage I accessed.

I'm thinking about two possibilities:

1-I closed the capture before receiving all the packets.

2-I followed a special transition on the TCP transition diagram so that only one FIN was necessary to close the connection...(is that possible?)

Comment: Can you please provide more information? If possible a copy of the packet capture would be great. If not a screenshot would do.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, it sounds like you had a multiple threads for one website. This would explain why you saw two handshakes and why you were expecting to see two FINs. The most likely answer is that, as you mentioned, you stopped the capture before the second FIN was sent. Or perhaps a RESET was used to terminate the second connection instead. In regards to your question, no, it's not possible to bring down two separate TCP connections with a single FIN packet.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a half close

> What are Half Closed Connections? Or: It's Not a Bug--it's a Feature!
>
> Every TCP connection consists of two half-connection which are closed
> independently of each other. So if one end sends a FIN, then the other
> end is free to just ACK that FIN (instead of FIN+ACK-ing it), which
> signals the FIN-sending end that it still has data to send
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/298919/what-is-tcp-half-open-connection-and-tcp-half-closed-connection